# Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE) projectRaster

Tags: raster, r

I am running into an error : `Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)`, after trying following code:

```
# Load the raster package
library(raster)

# Read the raster file
r <- raster("n41_w080_1arc_v2.tif")
r2 <- raster("n39_w079_1arc_v2.tif")
print(r)

class : RasterLayer dimensions : 3601, 3601, 12967201 (nrow, ncol, ncell) 
resolution : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778 (x, y) 
extent : -80.00014, -78.99986, 40.99986, 42.00014 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) 
crs : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source : n41_w080_1arc_v2.tif 
names : n41_w080_1arc_v2 
values : 248, 694 (min, max) 

# Define the projection
utm17 <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

# Project the rasters to UTM 17
options(warn=1)
r_proj <- projectRaster(r, crs = utm17)
```

Is there anything that I can do about this? reinstalled the raster package a few times.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I can't get this error with a simple raster of my own construction. Can you show us the output of `print(r)`? What's the effect of `options(warn=1)`?

Comment: > print(r)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3601, 3601, 12967201  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent     : -80.00014, -78.99986, 40.99986, 42.00014  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : n41_w080_1arc_v2.tif 
names      : n41_w080_1arc_v2 
values     : 248, 694  (min, max)

Comment: Still works for me with a raster of that dimension, extent, resolution, and CRS. Run the code again, and after the error run `traceback()` to show more details about where the error occurs. Edit your question and add the traceback information (don't add it to a comment like you did the "print" info).